# How to improve DB configuration

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I have a MySQL 5.5 database, with 58 tables, ~14,188,772 rows, 19.9 GB in size. I want to mention that 19.5 GB of those is in one table.

I've never changed the configuration, but after recent performance issues, I stumbled across the variable everyone seems to mention first: `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Everywhere I looked I saw its value set to multiple GB's, then I checked my own, and it's (the default) 128 MB.

I found a query in [another thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size) that aims to calculate the right buffer pool size. I ran this query and it told me that 32 GB would be the right amount in my case. On the other hand, that thread calls 20 GB enourmous. I have 16 GB RAM in the server, does this mean I need 32+ for the DB to function optimally?

This worries me I'm running a hugely misconfigured database. Can someone enlighten me about what one usually needs to change in a DB configuration? The settings that need "fiddling" to get right, the things that I should never touch?

Here is my entire "server variables"  page from phpmyadmin:

```
Variable                                            Session value / Global value    
auto increment increment                            1   
auto increment offset                               1   
autocommit                                          ON  
automatic sp privileges                             ON  
back log                                            50  
basedir                                             /usr    
big tables                                          OFF     
binlog cache size                                   32,768  
binlog direct non transactional updates             OFF     
binlog format                                       STATEMENT   
binlog stmt cache size                              32,768  
bulk insert buffer size                             8,388,608   
character set client                                utf8    
(Global value)                                      latin1  
character set connection                            utf8    
(Global value)                                      latin1  
character set database                              latin1  
character set filesystem                            binary  
character set results                               utf8    
(Global value)                                      latin1  
character set server                                latin1  
character set system                                utf8    
character sets dir                                  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/  
collation connection                                utf8_general_ci     
(Global value)                                      latin1_swedish_ci   
collation database                                  latin1_swedish_ci   
collation server                                    latin1_swedish_ci   
completion type                                     NO_CHAIN    
concurrent insert                                   AUTO    
connect timeout                                     10  
datadir                                             /var/lib/mysql/     
date format                                         %Y-%m-%d    
datetime format                                     %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s   
default storage engine                              InnoDB  
default week format                                 0   
delay key write                                     ON  
delayed insert limit                                100     
delayed insert timeout                              300     
delayed queue size                                  1,000   
div precision increment                             4   
engine condition pushdown                           ON  
error count                                         0   
(Global value)                                      0   
event scheduler                                     OFF     
expire logs days                                    10  
external user           
(Global value)      
flush                                               OFF     
flush time                                          0   
foreign key checks                                  ON  
ft boolean syntax                                   + -><()~*:""&|  
ft max word len                                     84  
ft min word len                                     4   
ft query expansion limit                            20  
ft stopword file                                    (built-in)  
general log                                         OFF     
general log file                                    /var/lib/mysql/xxx.log  
group concat max len                                1,024   
have compress                                       YES     
have crypt                                          YES     
have csv                                            YES     
have dynamic loading                                YES     
have geometry                                       YES     
have innodb                                         YES     
have ndbcluster                                     NO  
have openssl                                        DISABLED    
have partitioning                                   YES     
have profiling                                      YES     
have query cache                                    YES     
have rtree keys                                     YES     
have ssl                                            DISABLED    
have symlink                                        YES     
hostname                                            xxx
identity                                            0   
(Global value)                                      0   
ignore builtin innodb                               OFF     
init connect        
init file       
init slave      
innodb adaptive flushing                            ON  
innodb adaptive hash index                          ON  
innodb additional mem pool size                     8,388,608   
innodb autoextend increment                         8   
innodb autoinc lock mode                            1   
innodb buffer pool instances                        1   
innodb buffer pool size                             134,217,728     
innodb change buffering                             all     
innodb checksums                                    ON  
innodb commit concurrency                           0   
innodb concurrency tickets                          500     
innodb data file path                               ibdata1:10M:autoextend  
innodb data home dir        
innodb doublewrite                                  ON  
innodb fast shutdown                                1   
innodb file format                                  Antelope    
innodb file format check                            ON  
innodb file format max                              Antelope    
innodb file per table                               OFF     
innodb flush log at trx commit                      1   
innodb flush method         
innodb force load corrupted                         OFF     
innodb force recovery                               0   
innodb io capacity                                  200     
innodb large prefix                                 OFF     
innodb lock wait timeout                            50  
innodb locks unsafe for binlog                      OFF     
innodb log buffer size                              8,388,608   
innodb log file size                                5,242,880   
innodb log files in group                           2   
innodb log group home dir                           ./  
innodb max dirty pages pct                          75  
innodb max purge lag                                0   
innodb mirrored log groups                          1   
innodb old blocks pct                               37  
innodb old blocks time                              0   
innodb open files                                   300     
innodb print all deadlocks                          OFF     
innodb purge batch size                             20  
innodb purge threads                                0   
innodb random read ahead                            OFF     
innodb read ahead threshold                         56  
innodb read io threads                              4   
innodb replication delay                            0   
innodb rollback on timeout                          OFF     
innodb rollback segments                            128     
innodb spin wait delay                              6   
innodb stats method                                 nulls_equal     
innodb stats on metadata                            ON  
innodb stats sample pages                           8   
innodb strict mode                                  OFF     
innodb support xa                                   ON  
innodb sync spin loops                              30  
innodb table locks                                  ON  
innodb thread concurrency                           0   
innodb thread sleep delay                           10,000  
innodb use native aio                               OFF     
innodb use sys malloc                               ON  
innodb version                                      5.5.31  
innodb write io threads                             4   
insert id                                           0   
(Global value)                                      0   
interactive timeout                                 28,800  
join buffer size                                    131,072     
keep files on create                                OFF     
key buffer size                                     16,777,216  
key cache age threshold                             300     
key cache block size                                1,024   
key cache division limit                            100     
large files support                                 ON  
large page size                                     0   
large pages                                         OFF     
last insert id                                      0   
(Global value)                                      0   
lc messages                                         en_US   
lc messages dir                                     /usr/share/mysql/   
lc time names                                       en_US   
license                                             GPL     
local infile                                        ON  
lock wait timeout                                   31,536,000  
locked in memory                                    OFF     
log                                                 OFF     
log bin                                             OFF     
log bin trust function creators                     OFF     
log error       
log output                                          FILE    
log queries not using indexes                       OFF     
log slave updates                                   OFF     
log slow queries                                    OFF     
log warnings                                        1   
long query time                                     10  
low priority updates                                OFF     
lower case file system                              OFF     
lower case table names                              0   
max allowed packet                                  16,777,216  
max binlog cache size                               18446744073709547520    
max binlog size                                     104,857,600     
max binlog stmt cache size                          18446744073709547520    
max connect errors                                  10  
max connections                                     151     
max delayed threads                                 20  
max error count                                     64  
max heap table size                                 16,777,216  
max insert delayed threads                          20  
max join size                                       18446744073709551615    
max length for sort data                            1,024   
max long data size                                  16,777,216  
max prepared stmt count                             16,382  
max relay log size                                  0   
max seeks for key                                   18446744073709551615    
max sort length                                     1,024   
max sp recursion depth                              0   
max tmp tables                                      32  
max user connections                                0   
max write lock count                                18446744073709551615    
metadata locks cache size                           1,024   
min examined row limit                              0   
multi range count                                   256     
myisam data pointer size                            6   
myisam max sort file size                           9223372036853727232     
myisam mmap size                                    18446744073709551615    
myisam recover options                              BACKUP  
myisam repair threads                               1   
myisam sort buffer size                             8,388,608   
myisam stats method                                 nulls_unequal   
myisam use mmap                                     OFF     
net buffer length                                   16,384  
net read timeout                                    30  
net retry count                                     10  
net write timeout                                   60  
new                                                 OFF     
old                                                 OFF     
old alter table                                     OFF     
old passwords                                       OFF     
open files limit                                    1,024   
optimizer prune level                               1   
optimizer search depth                              62  
optimizer switch                                    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on  
performance schema                                  OFF     
performance schema events waits history long size   10,000  
performance schema events waits history size        10  
performance schema max cond classes                 80  
performance schema max cond instances               1,000   
performance schema max file classes                 50  
performance schema max file handles                 32,768  
performance schema max file instances               10,000  
performance schema max mutex classes                200     
performance schema max mutex instances              1,000,000   
performance schema max rwlock classes               30  
performance schema max rwlock instances             1,000,000   
performance schema max table handles                100,000     
performance schema max table instances              50,000  
performance schema max thread classes               50  
performance schema max thread instances             1,000   
pid file                                            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid  
plugin dir                                          /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/  
port                                                3,306   
preload buffer size                                 32,768  
profiling                                           OFF     
profiling history size                              15  
protocol version                                    10  
proxy user      
(Global value)      
pseudo slave mode                                   OFF     
(Global value)      
pseudo thread id                                    49,037  
(Global value)                                      0   
query alloc block size                              8,192   
query cache limit                                   1,048,576   
query cache min res unit                            4,096   
query cache size                                    16,777,216  
query cache type                                    ON  
query cache wlock invalidate                        OFF     
query prealloc size                                 8,192   
rand seed1                                          0   
(Global value)                                      0   
rand seed2                                          0   
(Global value)                                      0   
range alloc block size                              4,096   
read buffer size                                    131,072     
read only                                           OFF     
read rnd buffer size                                262,144     
relay log       
relay log index         
relay log info file                                 relay-log.info  
relay log purge                                     ON  
relay log recovery                                  OFF     
relay log space limit                               0   
report host         
report password         
report port                                         3,306   
report user         
rpl recovery rank                                   0   
secure auth                                         OFF     
secure file priv        
server id                                           0   
skip external locking                               ON  
skip name resolve                                   OFF     
skip networking                                     OFF     
skip show database                                  OFF     
slave compressed protocol                           OFF     
slave exec mode                                     STRICT  
slave load tmpdir                                   /tmp    
slave max allowed packet                            1,073,741,824   
slave net timeout                                   3,600   
slave skip errors                                   OFF     
slave transaction retries                           10  
slave type conversions      
slow launch time                                    2   
slow query log                                      OFF     
slow query log file                                 /var/lib/mysql/bl07-slow.log    
socket                                              /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock     
sort buffer size                                    2,097,152   
sql auto is null                                    OFF     
sql big selects                                     ON  
sql big tables                                      OFF     
sql buffer result                                   OFF     
sql log bin                                         ON  
sql log off                                         OFF     
sql low priority updates                            OFF     
sql max join size                                   18446744073709551615    
sql mode        
sql notes                                           ON  
sql quote show create                               ON  
sql safe updates                                    OFF     
sql select limit                                    18446744073709551615    
sql slave skip counter                              0   
sql warnings                                        OFF     
ssl ca      
ssl capath      
ssl cert        
ssl cipher      
ssl key         
storage engine                                      InnoDB  
stored program cache                                256     
sync binlog                                         0   
sync frm                                            ON  
sync master info                                    0   
sync relay log                                      0   
sync relay log info                                 0   
system time zone                                    CEST    
table definition cache                              400     
table open cache                                    400     
thread cache size                                   8   
thread concurrency                                  10  
thread handling                                     one-thread-per-connection   
thread stack                                        196,608     
time format                                         %H:%i:%s    
time zone                                           SYSTEM  
timed mutexes                                       OFF     
timestamp                                           1,399,897,257   
(Global value)                                      0   
tmp table size                                      16,777,216  
tmpdir                                              /tmp    
transaction alloc block size                        8,192   
transaction prealloc size                           4,096   
tx isolation                                        REPEATABLE-READ     
unique checks                                       ON  
updatable views with limit                          YES     
version                                             5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1     
version comment                                     (Ubuntu)    
version compile machine                             x86_64  
version compile os                                  debian-linux-gnu    
wait timeout                                        28,800  
warning count                                       0   
(Global value)                                      0
```

Comment: 32GB sounds a little big to me, considering your database is only 20GB! Assuming this is a dedicated DB server, you can probably go up to 10GB for the innodb cache (maybe even more)... This is of course assuming the table is in fact InnoDB ;-)

Comment: Higher buffer pool = more data that can be looked up from RAM rather than using hdd I/O to find it = faster. But performance also depends on what you do. If you're doing lots of searching / joining / filtering then you want large buffer pool. It's not uncommon to have large buffer pools (32 or more gigs). If you need it, and you can afford it - it's viable to go for lots of RAM for dedicated DB server.

Comment: Another place to start for general setting suggestions is here: https://tools.percona.com/wizard what ever you do, don't just drop the output straight into a production environment, change one setting at a time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by alter your configuration using 60% of available RAM for innodb_buffer_pool_size. By available i mean how much RAM can you dedicate to database. Of-course if your server runs only MySQL then 60% of physical RAM ( i whould have set it to 10G for start). The program you execute just calculate the database size (data and indexes) and make you the 32G suggestion.
In order not to overflow your memory use this site:
http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/